# How can I add UNIQUE Constraint in table via 'InstallSchema'?

Tags: magento2, database

I know the syntax to create table via **InstallSchema** in  Magento 2, but I don't know how to add a UNIQUE Constraint on two columns of my table.

Here is the syntax of my table  -

```
$table_mediatype = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($setup->getTable('mediatype'));
$table_mediatype->addColumn(
    'id',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    null,
    array('identity' => true,'nullable' => false,'primary' => true),
    'Entity ID'
);
$table_mediatype->addColumn(
    'mediadownloader_id',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    null,
    array('nullable' => false),
    'Mediadownloader ID'
);
$table_mediatype->addColumn(
    'product_id',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    null,
    array('nullable' => false),
    'Product ID'
);
$table_mediatype->addColumn(
    'media_type',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    25,
    array('nullable' => false),
    'Associated Media Type'
);
```

Via an SQL query we can add a UNIQUE Constraint like this  -

```
ALTER TABLE netzwelt_mediatype
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_product_id_with_media_type UNIQUE unique_product_id_with_media_type(
    `product_id` ,
    `media_type`
);
```

But I don't know how to add it via 'InstallSchema'. Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create `UNIQUE Constraint` you can use

`Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE`

For example,

```
      $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('mediatype')
        )->addColumn(
            'key',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            32,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Key code'
        )->addIndex(
            $installer->getIdxName(
                $installer->getTable('mediatype'),
                ['key'],
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
            ),
            ['key'],
            ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE]
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

**EDIT**

When you a look into

```
 public function addIndex($indexName, $fields, $options = [])
```

from

`Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table.php`

First, paramater is `$indexName` name which means the same you writes as `unique_product_id_with_media_type` (in core `php`) in my sample code I added

```
$installer->getIdxName(
                $installer->getTable('oauth_consumer'),
                ['key'],
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
            )
```

because It creates the same key(here `MEDIATYPE_KEY` where `mediatype` is table name and `key` is column name ) which you want based on the current table name and column name. (If you want you can pass `unique_product_id_with_media_type` here but it's not good practice )

the second parameter is `$fields` means the columns which you want to make unique you can pass the only column as a string or multiple columns as an array

and the last third paramater is `$options` from here you can tell which option you want (like `UNIQUE` or `FK`)

here on third option I passed as

`Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE` to create `unique` key

Comment: Is this code allow to alter one column to UNIQUE or it perform like my query doing .(See at the end of my code )....

Comment: It will add `UNIQUE Constraint `  so your column has unique value same like product SKU @Atul

Comment: As I need to make "product_id & media_type" both column sould have unique values as combination ....SO how can I write this....Because in your ans I didn't see where to write constraint-name like 'unique_product_id_with_media_type' and Unique index-name 'unique_product_id_with_media_type'  as we write in sql query ...

Comment: Please see my edit @Atul

Comment: thx for clarification....let me try via this ..........

Comment: It creates two different indexes, for each column as  -  MEDIATYPE_PRODUCT_ID   , MEDIATYPE_MEDIA_TYP'  . But I want one index for both columns - "`product_id` ,
    `media_type`" .............Plz check

Comment: It works, thx....Just need to pass ['key','key1'] for multiple fields. And instead of function generated indexName I gave my own index name  Like  - 

`$table_netzwelt_mediatype->addColumn(
            'media_type',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            25,
            array('nullable' => false),
            'Associated Media Type'
        )->addIndex(
            'unique_product_id_with_media_type',
            ['product_id','media_type'],
            ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE]
        );`